# Windows stuck on signing out

Tags: windows

My computer had been on the signing out screen for the past 3 hours. I suspect its stuck because my C: drive doesn't have enough space. (my E: drive is still spaceful)

Any ideas how I could interrupt this signing out and get back to the other logon user?

I've tried letting the battery almost die which trhgers hibernation. But sadly on unhibernate, it is still showing the signing out screen.

Answer (score 0):

Just hold (not just press, but truly hold) the power button until the screen goes black. Wait few seconds and press the power button again - the computer will boot in a regular sequence. You may see the message below - just select Start Windows Normally

Login and free up some space :-)

[image]